# UISplitViewController: How to present popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I've a `UISplitViewController` which is a `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` with the following delegate method:

> splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:

When the iPad is started in Portrait, I would like the Popover from the SplitView to be visible. How can I do that?

I've tried the following code:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    //setting the barButtonItem in the toolbar in the detail view.

    [pc presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
}
```

But the above code gives me the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there only one problem, wrong place to call presentPopover method, splitViewController:**WillHide**ViewController....... so, barButtonItem exist but not present on screen. i used next code and it worked for me.
For handle all cases u need to use 2 methods.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        if (self.view.window != nil) {
            [_masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
        }
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

and

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        if (self.view.window != nil) {
            [_masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you placing this code? I've tried to handle over the PopoverController pointer to my ViewController, but it seems that it, when I would like to present the popover, to be changed to nil.